# Google Sheets - get the value corresponding to maximum element in another column where the value is non-empty

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreatsheets for weight on a given date (it's new years). How can I create a formula that will return the non-empty value for the latest date.

```
A               C
2019-01-22      
2019-01-15      
2019-01-08      200
2019-01-01      191.4
```

So the result of this will return 200, since 2018-01-08 is the latest date that has a value for C and 200 is that value.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is no repeated date in column "A" and also if corresponding values are in column "B" you can use something like:

```
INDIRECT(
   ADDRESS(
      MATCH(
         MAX(
           FILTER(A2:A5,NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B5)))
         )
     ,A2:A5)
   ,2)
)
```

Note that the ending 2 is the column number of "B".

Answer (score 1):

Please try, for weight:

```
=index(C:C,match(maxifs(A:A,C:C,"<>"),A:A,0))
```

or for date (the 'engine' for above):

```
=maxifs(A:A,C:C,"<>")
```

Or, a little shorter:

```
=VLOOKUP(maxifs(A:A,C:C,"<>"),A:C,3,0)
```

Shorter still, if the sort order can be guaranteed:

```
=index(filter(C:C,C:C>0),1,1)
```